# How does a router/switch know which queue a packet should be put in?

Tags: cisco, router, qos

In weighted fair queuing, how does the router/switch/multiplexer know which queue to put a packet into? For example does it read the headers of each packet to find out the sender and the intended application?
[image: diagram]

For example how does "classify arrivals" work?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question to be less broad; we cannot take questions which lead to answers the size of wikipedia-articles.  If we don't limit this to one qos feature, the question is simply too broad

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

A network device generally has 3-4 queues for traffic handling. WFQ is not strictly speaking a queuing algorithm, it's a egress traffic scheduling algorithm. It determines how the traffic placed in different queues is sent out of the device. The way fair queuing works is that traffic placed on different queues is served in order, for example in case of three queues they would be served 1-2-3-1-2-3 and so on. We can give double weight for queue 1, in which case the queues would be served 1-1-2-3-1-1-2-3.

"Classifying arrivals" refers to the way ingress packets are handled within the device itself. Generally network devices uphold the existing priority of the traffic, placing incoming packets to appropriate egress queue based on what priority it has. However in every case the device actually looks into the frame itself, either the L2 or L3 header.

Ingress frames can be prioritized several different ways. We can use the ingress interface, or determine it by Layer 2 frame information such as 802.1p/Q priority (Class of Service, CoS), L2 MAC address or VLAN ID. This is how a L2 device such as a switch works. For example the packet may arrive in a specific "Voice" VLAN (used for VOIP traffic), in which case it will be placed in high priority egress queue. Or the frame header's 802.1Q VLAN Tag may contain a 3-bit PCP (Priority Code Point) field which determines which queue the packet is placed in.

A router as L3 device would look at the IP packet header in the frame payload. There's a wide range of ways to prioritize the traffic, from the incoming interface to the IP address, subnet, TCP/IP port number and so on. Most commonly used is probably DiffServ (Differentiated Services). This uses 6-bit Differentiated Services Code Point (DSCP) in 8-bit DS field in the packet header. This allows much more granulated priority categorization, in theory 64 (2^6) different priority levels. In practice however most networks use commonly defined per-hop behaviors:

- Default PHB - typically best-effort traffic, used for normal PC data
  traffic
- Expedited Forwarding (EF PHB) - used for low-loss,
  low-latency traffic, for example VOIP
- Assured Forwading (AF PHB) - ensures delivery under certain pre-defined conditions
- Class Selector PHB - maintains backward compatibility with previously used ToS (Type of Service) field in IPv4 header

More in-depth descriptions how traffic priorization works can be found for example in Wikipedia. Type of Service, Class of Service, Quality of Service, 802.1p and 802.1Q are good starting points.

Comment: Please consider adding information about wfq which is what was specified in the question

Comment: I didn't put that in the original answer as the question is how does a device decide which egress queue is used, not how the egerss queue packets are scheduled with WFQ is about. Updated nonetheless.

Comment: The answer as written still fails to answer the question. Keep in mind that Stack Exchange strongly discourages answering the main question as a hyperlink reference since the link could change making your answer irrelevant

Comment: While it's ambiguous which platform the OP is asking about, you're still missing the reality that wfq both classifies and schedules in the most common implementations that I can think of.

Comment: That's why I gave general answer. I didn't look at WFQ so much as I understand it's used as an example, not that the question is specifically "how does WFQ work". According to the same Cisco manual WFQ classifies traffic based on interface, address, protocol,  ports/sockets, or ToS. It's also IP Precedence- and DCSP-aware. Seems to me it's still prioritizing the traffic according to the traditional CoS/QoS priorities. But I'm not an expert on WFQ, so I might completely misunderstand it.

Comment: If we don't limit the question to one qos feature (i.e. wfq), we'd have to close the question as "too broad".  This user has a history of asking broad questions, and those really aren't a good fit on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Doesn't indeed get much broader than that :D My initial thought was "how the heck does one put QoS in a nutshell"... hence the initial short answer with external links. Thanks for the clarifications and tutoring - I'll keep these in mind :)

Answer (score 4):

> In queuing algorithms such as weighted fair queuing, how does the router/switch/multiplexer know which queue to put a packet into?
>
> ... For example how does "classify arrivals" work?

When [wfq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_fair_queueing) is enabled on an interface, the router builds a table of flows, and prioritizes low-bandwidth flows over high-bandwidth flows.  By prioritizing flows, it *classifies* lower bandwidth flows into a higher priority queue;  for more detail, see [Cisco's QoS config guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/fqos_c/qcfwfq.html#wp1000889):

> ```
> WFQ provides traffic priority management that automatically sorts among individual 
> traffic streams without requiring that you first define access lists. WFQ can 
> also manage duplex data streams such as those between pairs of applications, 
> and simplex data streams such as voice or video. There are two categories of WFQ 
> sessions: high bandwidth and low bandwidth. Low-bandwidth traffic has effective 
> priority over high-bandwidth traffic, and high-bandwidth traffic shares the 
> transmission service proportionally according to assigned weights.
>
> When WFQ is enabled for an interface, new messages for high-bandwidth traffic 
> streams are discarded after the configured or default congestive messages threshold 
> has been met. However, low-bandwidth conversations, which include control message 
> conversations, continue to enqueue data. As a result, the fair queue may occasionally 
> contain more messages than its configured threshold number specifies.
>
> With standard WFQ, packets are classified by flow. Packets with the same source IP 
> address, destination IP address, source TCP or User Datagram Protocol (UDP) 
> port, or destination TCP or UDP port belong to the same flow. WFQ allocates 
> an equal share of the bandwidth to each flow. Flow-based WFQ is also called 
> fair queueing because all flows are equally weighted.
> ```

One should also remember that QoS disciplines never kick in until there is congestion on the interface.  Finally, if possible, it's a good idea to manage queue depth with [wred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_random_early_detection) for all the reasons outlined in [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5316/how-are-weighted-fair-queuing-and-weighted-random-early-detection-related?rq=1)